# Как пропустить один из параметров?

Tags: javascript

```
var Anchor = {
  name: "Homo Sapiens",
  arms: 2,
  legs: 2,
  head: 1
}

var Man = function(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

Man.prototype = Anchor;
var nick = new Man('Nick', 45);
console.log(nick.name);   //Nick
```

Нужно сделать объект, который будет наследовать имя из своего прототипа. Надо пропустить первый параметр, но не знаю как.

```
var unknown = new Man('?' ,55);
console.log(unknown.name)    //Должно быть "Homo Sapiens"
```

Comment: как только ты присваиваешь значение поля в объекте, ты теряешь доступ к свойству из прототипа

Answer (score 0):

Ты можешь просто проверять аргументы в конструкторе:

```js
var Anchor = {
  name: "Homo Sapiens",
  arms: 2,
  legs: 2,
  head: 1
}

var Man = function(name, age) {
  if (name) this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

Man.prototype = Anchor;
var nick = new Man(null, 45);
console.log(nick.name);   // Homo Sapiens

// Другой вариант - считать количество аргументов и интерпретировать сигнатуру исходя из него

var Man1 = function (name, age) {
  if (arguments.length > 1) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  } else if (arguments.length == 1) {
    this.age = name;
  }
}
Man1.prototype = Anchor;

var yr19 = new Man1(19);
var Bob = new Man1('Bob', 32);

console.log((new Man1).name); // Homo Sapiens
console.log(yr19.name, yr19.age); // Homo Sapiens 19
console.log(Bob.name, Bob.age); // Bob 32
```

Comment: А почему бы не вот так: `this.name = name || Anchor.name;` ?

Comment: @YozhEzhi, зачем конструктору знать имя своего прототипа? Или это вместо прототипирования? Что тогда делать с остальными свойствами? В любом случае, поведение другое. После `Anchor.name='Anchor'` в вашем случае существующие объекты не изменятся.

Comment: Понял. Вы правы.